# Application upgrade needs a "Clear cache/clear data" to work

Tags: android

I did a major rewrite of my application to support fragment. I also took this opportunity to rewrite a bunch of code to make it more stable, cleaner, more maintainable, etc.

We pushed the new version on the Play Store. Unfortunately, some users complained that they had to clear the cache and the application data for the new version to work. Unfortunately, I don't have more information (as I can't contact these users). Clearing the cache and the data seems to fix the problem. I have no idea if the problem is that the app crash at startup. Or if the app start, but then is stuck in a endless loop.

We use Bugsense to have automatic bug reports. I've looked at them, but I can't seem to find the cause of the problem.

I'm curious as to what is stored and where. My app uses the "context.getExternalCacheDir()" to store images downloaded from the web. I store data in preference files, as well as in the SQL database. Before releasing the app, we had an internal QA to make sure the app upgrade was working perfectly. And most of our users don't have this problem.

What can I do to try to pinpoint the cause of this issue?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem might be, but this was the first thing that popped in my mind... maybe it helps... [Incompatible Serializations](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)